# disable previous date from jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using this datepicker code where I want to disable previous date from the datepicker

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        new datepickr('datepick');
        new datepickr('datepick1');

        new datepickr('datepick2', {
            'dateFormat': 'm/d/y'
        });

        new datepickr('datepick3', {
            'fullCurrentMonth': false,
            'dateFormat': 'l, F j'
        });

        new datepickr('datepick4', {
            dateFormat: '\\l\\e jS F Y', /* need to double escape characters that you don't want formatted */
            weekdays: ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi'],
            months: ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'],
            suffix: { 1: 'er' },
            defaultSuffix: '' /* the suffix that is used if nothing matches the suffix object, default 'th' */
        });

    </script>




 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="date/datepickr.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="date/datepickr.min.js"></script>



 <input id="datepick" class="text_field datepicker" name="fromdate" required="required" />
```

any help to disable  previous date will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to disable only one previous day or all days before the selected date?

Comment: It seems that you are using not jquery datepicker, but datepickr.js from https://code.google.com/p/datepickr. And those datepickr does not support disabling of dates!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    document.getElementsByName("myDate")[0].setAttribute('min', todayDate);
    $(".book_btn").click(function(){
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+("0" +(today.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
    //alert(date);//("0" + this.getDate()).slice(-2)
    document.getElementById("myDate").defaultValue =date;
    });<style type="text/css">
    input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```